# View Contents of Archive in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, zip

Aside from `unzip -l`, do I have any non-command line options for viewing an archive's contents on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[BetterZip Quick Look Generator](http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator).

[image]

Comment: This, as well as the commercial software by the same name, and its competitors.

Comment: @fideli, thanks, checking it out now. I wonder how it'll play with pathfinder, and also why I didn't ask that in the question :)

Comment: @Daniel Beck, its competitors? Who would that be?

Comment: wow, I think that Pathfinder already has this with QuickLook.

Comment: @Yar - zipQuickLook for one.. I know there are others as I have something different (but I'm not on my mac atm)

Comment: BetterZip works perfectly in Path Finder.

Comment: Thanks Fideli, I had kind of forgotten about the QuickLook feature.

Comment: @Yar: via iusethis, I found both [iArchiver](http://iarchiver.com/) (possibly more limited) and [Springy](http://www.springyarchiver.com/) (both untested, since I have Betterzip). I don't like the signup requirement of the Stuffit folks, but they might also offer something like this.

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Zipeg.app](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/23378/zipeg).

> Zipeg is an absolutely free universal .rar and .zip file opener. This tiny but mighty utility also opens .tar, .tgz, .bzip2 and many other compressed archives. Zipeg is very simple and intuitive to use and works on Snow Leopard, Leopard and Tiger on both Intel and PowerPC macs. Zipeg supports password protected and multipart zip and rar files.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't support .exe rar files

Comment: now it requires java se 6, which is not easily available.