# How to unzip selected files of a zip file in Mac

Tags: mac, zip

I have some very large zip files contains thousands of files. I only need to unzip one or two files within it. In Windows, this can be easily done with most common programs like WinRAR or WinZIP. But in Mac OS X, I cannot find any software with the same functionality.

Comment: Can you not just drag said files out of the folder? This is what I usually do but I use windows and I have very limited experience with any of the mac OS's

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/q/196227/303573

Comment: @RJHunter Would you please post a reply so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
unzip archive.zip path/inside/zip
```

Add `-j` (junk paths) to remove subdirectories.

Use `zipinfo` (equivalent to `unzip -Z`) or `unzip -l` to list files.

Comment: Thank you. This is a way but must I use command line to complete this task? Isn't there any GUI applications available for this?

Answer (score 3):

For the records, there are/were various UI options able to browse zip's contents and extract them selectively. The ones I know:

- [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/)
- [The Archive Browser](https://theunarchiver.com/)
- [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com/)
- [Zipeg](https://code.google.com/archive/p/zipeg) (this one stopped development, I think)

However, if you know the path to the files you wanna extract, it may be more efficient (and cheap) the command-line suggested above.

Comment: "The Archive Browser" is no longer in development, and has been replaced with (or reverted to?) The Unarchiver - which removed all relevant functionality.  It's remarkable how many apps do the same one thing, and how few actually allow you to manipulate archives in more powerful and useful ways, like Pacifist and BetterZip.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal: `brew install p7zip`

then just unzip using : `7z x [path-of-file]`

or first `cd [path of the file]` and then `7z x [file]`

Comment: OP said, in comment above, they want to use GUI.